# C# Generic Method T Class T Override

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

In C# I have a generic class that looks like this:

```
public class DataManager<T> : IDisposable where T : class
```

That is used like this:

```
    public T GetById(String id)
    {
        return this.Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
```

This works great.

However if I have 2 types in a manager, in this case, Ticket and TicketResponse, I would like to be able to override the type without having to add the type into every method call. Something like this:

```
    public T GetById<T>(String id) where T : class
    {
        return this.Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
```

Where I can call it interchangeably like so:

```
    var ticket = GetById(myId);
    var ticketResponse = GetById<TicketResponse>(myId); // this would override
```

The idea is to not have to create a separate manager for a sub-object, but also to not have to get the entire ticket to have to iterate through the responses, but just be able to get it directly.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not have a `DataManager<TicketResponse>`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't have to make `DataManger` generic, just make the method `GetById` generic as in your post.

Comment: Alex, I could, but I would rather keep my ticket entity and it's dependents (responses) together, "The idea is to not have to create a separate manager for a sub-object"

Comment: Hamlet, I don't want to have to pass the class every single time I use it. It'd be nice to just have it the first time and then only if I need to override so my code is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Alex, that isn't true. It is a property of it, but I am also pulling it in as a set in my DataContext. So I can access it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public T GetById( String id )
{
    return GetById<T>( id );
}

public U GetById<U>( String id ) where U : T
{
    return this.Context.Set<U>().Find( id );
}
```

So you have your original method but also an additional generic method which can take another parameter type that derives from `T`.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this. Running slow today. I changed it though so GetById calls GetById<U> to avoid code duplication and added the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Context.Set` allows you to specify any `T` you want, you could add an interface for the `DataManager` class, add a base class which exposes a method on the underlying context and then implement the interface explicitly on your manager class:

```
public interface IDataManager<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    T GetById(string id);
}

public class DataManagerBase : IDisposable
{
    protected Find<T>(string id) where T : class
    {
        return this.Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
}

public class TicketManager : DataManagerBase, IDataManager<TicketResponse>, IDataManager<Ticket>
{
    TicketResponse IDataManager<TicketResponse>.GetById(string id)
    {
        return this.Find<TicketResponse>(id);
    }

    Ticket IDataManager<Ticket>.GetById(string id)
    {
        return this.Find<TicketResponse>(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `Ticket` is a special case: `Ticket`'s DataManager should *also* provide methods for `TicketResponse`. Is that correct?

In that case, you can just subclass `DataManager<T>` and add the required functionality:

```
class TicketManager : DataManager<Ticket>
{
    public TicketResponse GetResponseById(String id)
    {
        return this.Context.Set<TicketResponse>().Find(id);
    }
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
var ticket = myTicketManager.GetById(myId);
var ticketResponse = myTicketManager.GetResponseById(myId);
```

*(If you are worried about the duplication of the `GetById` code, just extract it into a static protected `GetByIdInternal<TData>` method.)*

Comment: You're absolutely right, and this is exactly the code I already have (seriously, to the character)! So great minds think alike. But, I also have this for individual Save and Delete generic ticket/custom response methods. What I'm trying to do is not have the custom code so all of my entities use the same code and I can change it (if I need to in the future), and write tests, all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper that encapsulates *two* DataManagers:

```
class DataAndResponseManager<TData, TResponse>
{
    private dataManager = new DataManager<TData>();
    private responseManager = new DataManager<TResponse>();

    public TData GetById(String id) { dataManager.GetById(id); }
    public TResponse GetResponseById(String id) { responseManager.GetById(id); }
}
```

Advantage: Reuse of all existing DataManager code.

Disadvantage: Proxy methods required.